# Can i choose Illustrator artboard preset using script?

Tags: javascript, adobe

I have a question! Can i choose Illustrator artboard preset using script?

I would like to create a new artboard with "fit to artwork bound preset". I have searched on the Internet, read Adobe API and stuff...  but not a single thing that i have found that are related to  "artboard preset"... So, Can i choose Illustrator artboard preset using script? And if it is posible? can you give me some example or link... etc... i will apreciated!

Thanks for reading!
And have a nice day!